# Apply multiple StandardScaler's to individual groups?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Is there a pythonic way to chain together sklearn's StandardScaler instances to independently scale data with groups? I.e., if I wanted to find independently scale  the features of the iris dataset; I could use the following code:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
df['class'] = data['target']

means = df.groupby('class').mean()
stds = df.groupby('class').std()

df_rescaled = (
    (df.drop(['class'], 1) - means.reindex(df['class']).values) / 
     stds.reindex(df['class']).values)
```

Here, I'm subtracting by the mean and dividing by the stdev of each group independently. But Its somewhat hard to carry around these means and stdev's, and essentially, replicate the behavior of `StandardScaler` when I have a categorical variable I'd like to control for.

Is there a more pythonic / sklearn-friendly way to implement this type of scaling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, you can use any `sklearn` operation and apply it to a `groupby` object.

First, a little convenience wrapper:

```
import typing
import pandas as pd

class SklearnWrapper:
    def __init__(self, transform: typing.Callable):
        self.transform = transform

    def __call__(self, df):
        transformed = self.transform.fit_transform(df.values)
        return pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

This one will apply any `sklearn` transform you pass into it to a group.

And finally simple usage:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"], columns=data["feature_names"])
df["class"] = data["target"]

df_rescaled = (
    df.groupby("class")
    .apply(SklearnWrapper(StandardScaler()))
    .drop("class", axis="columns")
)
```

**EDIT:** You can pretty much do anything with `SklearnWrapper`.
Here is an example of **transforming and reversing this operation for each group (e.g. do not overwrite the transformation object)** - just fit the object anew each time a new group is seen (and add it to `list`).

I have kinda replicated a bit of `sklearn's` functionality for easier usage (you can extend it with any function you want by passing appropriate `string` to `_call_with_function` internal method):

```
class SklearnWrapper:
    def __init__(self, transformation: typing.Callable):
        self.transformation = transformation
        self._group_transforms = []
        # Start with -1 and for each group up the pointer by one
        self._pointer = -1

    def _call_with_function(self, df: pd.DataFrame, function: str):
        # If pointer >= len we are making a new apply, reset _pointer
        if self._pointer >= len(self._group_transforms):
            self._pointer = -1
        self._pointer += 1
        return pd.DataFrame(
            getattr(self._group_transforms[self._pointer], function)(df.values),
            columns=df.columns,
            index=df.index,
        )

    def fit(self, df):
        self._group_transforms.append(self.transformation.fit(df.values))
        return self

    def transform(self, df):
        return self._call_with_function(df, "transform")

    def fit_transform(self, df):
        self.fit(df)
        return self.transform(df)

    def inverse_transform(self, df):
        return self._call_with_function(df, "inverse_transform")
```

Usage (group transform, inverse operation and apply it again):

```
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"], columns=data["feature_names"])
df["class"] = data["target"]

# Create scaler outside the class
scaler = SklearnWrapper(StandardScaler())

# Fit and transform data (holding state)
df_rescaled = df.groupby("class").apply(scaler.fit_transform)

# Inverse the operation
df_inverted = df_rescaled.groupby("class").apply(scaler.inverse_transform)

# Apply transformation once again
df_transformed = (
    df_inverted.groupby("class")
    .apply(scaler.transform)
    .drop("class", axis="columns")
)
```

Comment: Cool solution! So that works, but unfortunately you lose the ability to transform new data. (or inverse_transform the old data) Apologies for not putting that in the original question. This seems to overwrite the SklearnWrapper.transform class for each group.

Comment: Is that what you wanted? You can do other stuff with it (pretty extensible) depending on your end goal.

Comment: So this is great, thanks so much for the help! I was hoping I'd get away with *less* code, but this is definitely more re-usable. I'll also just caution that this could cause problems up if groups were missing from a test dataset (or if new groups were added) without raising an error, but I don't see a way around that using the groupby / apply syntax.

Comment: I think you could extend it with `filter`, implementation of `partial_fit`-like function but it would clutter the image. IMO no need if you don't need it right now (or you can create a new issue if you do).

Comment: I used this but if my class column is category, it returns an error. Do you have a solution for this case?
@SzymonMaszke

Comment: This is giving wrong results when trying to invert the rescaled dataframe to the original one. @SzymonMaszke

Comment: @Indrajit What is the problem exactly? I'm basically passing the responsibility for results to `sklearn` here, but please correct me if I'm wrong (an edit with explanation would be great, thanks).

Comment: Hi @SzymonMaszke, I am running the same example as above. When I generate df_rescaled, the column "class" contains value 0 for all the rows. As a result when you do an inverse transform, the results are wrong.

Comment: In fit method, _group_transforms.append is not gonna add duplicates? What am I missing here?

Comment: I am having the same issue as rasyidstat
@SzymonMaszke can u suggest a solution for categorical value which you are grouping by

Answer (score 1):

I updated @Szymon Maszke code:

```
class SklearnWrapper:


def __init__(self, transformation: typing.Callable):
    self.transformation = transformation
    self._group_transforms = []
    # Start with -1 and for each group up the pointer by one
    self._pointer = -1

def _call_with_function(self, df: pd.DataFrame, function: str):
    # If pointer >= len we are making a new apply, reset _pointer
    if self._pointer == len(self._group_transforms)-1 and function=="inverse_transform":
        self._pointer = -1
    self._pointer += 1
    print(self._pointer)
    return pd.DataFrame(
        getattr(self._group_transforms[self._pointer], function)(df.values),
        columns=df.columns,
        index=df.index,
    )

def fit(self, df):
    scaler = copy(self.transformation)
    self._group_transforms.append(scaler.fit(df.values))
    return self

def transform(self, df):
    return self._call_with_function(df, "transform")

def fit_transform(self, df):
    self.fit(df)
    return self.transform(df)

def inverse_transform(self, df):
    return self._call_with_function(df, "inverse_transform")
```

`StandardScaler()` was not stored properly in `_group_transforms`, so I created a copy (using the copy lib) and store it (maybe there's a better way to do it using OOP).