# Scale multiple columns in a dataframe with the same preprocessor in SciKit Learn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

In the dataframe below I want to scale Open, High, Low, Close with the same min and max values within each Symbol.

I can do this with the following code, but is there a reasonable way to implement this with SciKit Learn preprocessors?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A', 10, 11, 9, 9, 100],
                   [2, 'A', 9, 13, 9, 12, 150],
                   [3, 'A', 12, 15, 11, 15, 130],
                   [1, 'B', 90, 95, 90, 92, 10],
                   [2, 'B', 92, 93, 84, 85, 13],
                   [3, 'B', 85, 88, 81, 83, 11]],
                  columns=['Timestamp', 'Symbol', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])

df.set_index(['Timestamp', 'Symbol', 'Volume'], inplace=True)
((df.stack() - df.stack().groupby('Symbol').min()) / (df.stack().groupby('Symbol').max() - df.stack().groupby('Symbol').min())).unstack().reset_index(['Volume'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems like the following code will work, but I'm not sure if this is really the "right" way to do it:

```
df.set_index(['Timestamp', 'Symbol', 'Volume'], inplace=True)
df = df.stack().to_frame().groupby('Symbol').apply(SklearnWrapper(MinMaxScaler()))[0].unstack().reset_index()
```

I got the SklearnWrapper from [Apply multiple StandardScaler's to individual groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55601928/2216002)

````
import typing
import pandas as pd

class SklearnWrapper:
    def __init__(self, transform: typing.Callable):
        self.transform = transform

    def __call__(self, df):
        transformed = self.transform.fit_transform(df.values)
        return pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)```
````