# Pandas groupby and sklearn compose – carry various keys through apply pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Suppose I have a DataFrame like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x0': [1, 2, np.nan, 5],
        'x1': [4, 5, 6, 10],
        'group': [2, 10, 10, 2],
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
)
```

I want to apply some arbitrary estimator/estimator union to each column prefixed with `x`, so I come up with some compose estimator like this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: StandardScaler().fit_transform(x.drop(['group', 'id'], axis=1))).explode().values.tolist())
#      0    1
# 0 -1.0 -1.0
# 1  1.0  1.0
# 2  0.0 -1.0
# 3  NaN  1.0
```

As we see, there's really not a great way of tracking which group or index (`id` column) to which these rows belong. I am not interested in inverse-transforming these scaled features. How can I keep track of the `group` and `id` columns in such a pipeline?

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601928/apply-multiple-standardscalers-to-individual-groups) but couldn't get the primary key and other features I want to carry along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right idea, but you can simplify and clean up your code on several parts by using the pandas methods in the correct way:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

ct = make_column_transformer(
    (StandardScaler(), df.head(1).filter(like='x').columns),
    remainder='passthrough'
)

data = df.groupby('group').apply(ct.fit_transform).explode()
pd.DataFrame(data.tolist(), columns=df.columns)
```

```
    x0   x1  group   id
0 -1.0 -1.0    2.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0    2.0  4.0
2  0.0 -1.0   10.0  2.0
3  NaN  1.0   10.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, using `sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer`:

```py
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
columns_to_transform = [c for c in df if c not in ['group', 'id']]
columns_not_to_transform = ['group', 'id']
all_columns = columns_to_transform + columns_not_to_transform
obj = make_column_transformer(
    (StandardScaler(), columns_to_transform),
    ('passthrough', columns_not_to_transform),
)
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: obj.fit_transform(x)).explode().values.tolist()).rename(columns = dict(zip(range(len(all_columns)), all_columns)))
    x0   x1  group   id
0 -1.0 -1.0    2.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0    2.0  4.0
2  0.0 -1.0   10.0  2.0
3  NaN  1.0   10.0  3.0
```